# layout issue with tabularx

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn, layout

This is my fsmpic.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass[version=last]{scrlttr2}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\KOMAoption{parskip}{full-}
\RequirePackage[a4paper,]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{ltablex}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}

\keepXColumns
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{\L}{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\setlength{\lightrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% MyEnviron
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{MyEnviron}[3]{%
    \newcounter{fsmpic@MyCounter}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
            L{15mm}%
            \L%
            L{25mm}%
            L{15mm}%
            R{25mm}%
            R{25mm}%
        }%
        \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{Menge} & \textbf{USt.} & \textbf{Einzelpreis} & \textbf{Summe} \\%
        \toprule\endhead%
        \BODY%
        \midrule%
        \multicolumn{5}{\L}{Some Text} & #1 \\%
        \MyCommand{#2}%
        \bottomrule%
        \multicolumn{5}{\L}{\textbf{More Text}} & \textbf{#3}%
    \end{tabularx}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyCommand}{ >{ \SplitList {,} } m }
 {
    \ProcessList {#1} {\fsmpic_process_argument:n}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \fsmpic_process_argument:n
 {
  \fsmpic_column:nn #1
 }
 \cs_new_protected:Nn \fsmpic_column:nn
 {
  \multicolumn{5}{\L}{Text #1 Another Text} & #2 \\
  \penalty0
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\MySecondCommand}[5]{\stepcounter{fsmpic@MyCounter}\thefsmpic@MyCounter & #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5 \\}
```

And this is my tex.tex:

```
\documentclass[tex]{fsmpic}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}

    \opening{Opening,}

    \begin{MyEnviron}{Number A}{{B}{C},{D}{E}}{F}
        \MySecondCommand{Some Text}{G}{H}{I}{J}
    \end{MyEnviron}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The SplitList works nicely, however, the layout of the tabularx with the multiline from `\fsmpic_column` is completly broken.

[image: image of broken layout]

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Condensed file for easier testing

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\keepXColumns
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{\L}{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\setlength{\lightrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% MyEnviron
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{MyEnviron}[3]{
    \newcounter{fsmpic@MyCounter}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
            L{15mm}
            X
            L{25mm}
            L{15mm}
            R{25mm}
            R{25mm}
        }
        \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} & \textbf{F} \\
        \toprule\endhead
        \BODY
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{\L}{Some Text} & #1 \\
        \MyCommand{#2}
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{5}{\L}{\textbf{More Text}} & \textbf{#3}
    \end{tabularx}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyCommand}{ >{ \SplitList {,} } m }
 {
    \ProcessList {#1} {\fsmpic_process_argument:n}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \fsmpic_process_argument:n
 {
  \fsmpic_column:nn #1
 }
 \cs_new_protected:Nn \fsmpic_column:nn
 {
  \multicolumn{5}{\L}{Text #1 Another Text} & #2 \\
  \penalty0
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\MySecondCommand}[5]{\stepcounter{fsmpic@MyCounter}\thefsmpic@MyCounter & #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5 \\}

\begin{document}

    \begin{MyEnviron}{Number A}{{B}{C},{D}{E}}{F}
        \MySecondCommand{Some Text}{G}{H}{I}{J}
    \end{MyEnviron}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please always provide a small complete test file, not disconnected fragments that can't be tested. xparse is not needed in current latex and you have not shown any definitions for `L` or `R` columns (or `\L` ???) column, or  `\toprule` or `\endhead` commands which are not defined in any of the packages you mention

Comment: Sorry, my first question :)
I have added full files.

Comment: The instruction `\newcolumntype{\L}{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}` looks suspicious. Why "`\L`"?

Comment: Why do you split your example into two files? While it is not difficult to copy and save a file it is nevertheless a nuisance as it involves more steps (and I have to type the class name (and get it right)). If everything were in one file I could simply copy&paste into my testfile.

Comment: I have added a condensed file.
@Mico This is for some other specific layouting, changing the "\L" in the tabularx to "X" does not solve the issue.

Comment: @Kompetenzfrosch - I did *not* claim that fixing `\L` would "solve the [main] issue".

Comment: You can't have `\multicolumn` inside `\MyCommand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `\L` as a column type, because this is an existing command. I use `M` instead.

The problem is that `\multicolumn` *must* appear first (after expansion) in a table cell, but your `\MyCommand` isn't expandable.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\MyCommand}{ m }
 {
    \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \fsmpic_process_argument:n
 }
\cs_new:Nn \fsmpic_process_argument:n
 {
  \fsmpic_column:nn #1
 }
 \cs_new:Nn \fsmpic_column:nn
 {
  \multicolumn{5}{M}{Text #1 Another Text} & #2 \\
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

By the way, `environ` is to be considered obsolete.

```
\newcounter{fsmpic@MyCounter}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyEnviron}{mmm+b}{%
    \setcounter{fsmpic@MyCounter}{0}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
            L{15mm}
            X
            L{25mm}
            L{15mm}
            R{25mm}
            R{25mm}
        }
        \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} & \textbf{F} \\
        \toprule\endhead
        #4
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{M}{Some Text} & #1 \\
        \MyCommand{#2}
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{5}{M}{\textbf{More Text}} & \textbf{#3}
    \end{tabularx}
}{}
```

Of course, `\newcounter` ***must*** be outside the definition of the environment.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved it.